# socket.io: Is it safe to store sensitive data inside the handshake object?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I would like to save some user sensitive data in the handshake object. The server side code looks something like this:

```
io.configure(function (){
 io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {

   var objAuthorized = IsUserAuthorized(handshakeData);

   if (objAuthorized.authorized) {
        handshakeData.password = objAuthorized.password; // Store sensitive data inside handshake
        handshakeData.email = objAuthorized.email; // Store sensitive data inside handshake
        callback(null, true);
     } else {
        callback(null, false);
     }

  });
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('do something', function() {
     if DoSomething(socket.handshake.password, socket.handshake.email) {
        // do something here
     }
  });
});
```

The above example was taken from https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing .

Is it safe to save sensitive data in the handshake object? Can a client somehow modify this data during the lifetime of his socket connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as know, there hasn't been any problem with this, a user can't get privileges from the authorization in `socket.io` .. but its not considered a good way or good practice to do this.

Most of developers won't do this, they handle authentication/authorization in other part of their application and leave to cookies and sessions validation on `socket.io`. This will also remove an overhead on the socket.io server.

---

*updated*

the following examples show how to work with sessions express/socket.io

some useful links :

- http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth
- https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing

Note that you have to authenticate the user in a common login form, matching credentials against a database, if you have worked previously with PHP and user authentication you wont have a problem. After matching the user credentials you set the sessionID and any other data, then the rest is handled by express.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Can you provide a simple example how most developers handle authentication/authorization?

Comment: Ok. So I guess it's safe to store sensitive data in the handshake object after authorization.

Comment: It's pretty obvious, that if you want, let's say, to save authentication info only for a lifetime of a socket, then making node to run whole circle of requesting db for session, working with it and saving back - would be a really inefficient.